# Amazon EC2 Windows shared volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012

I'm trying to setup a shared volume/folder between 2 EC2 instances running Windows Server 2012 and I'm failing miserably...

Both instances are on the same Security Group, and these are the rules:

[image]

And I shared a folder from the 1st instance (following this tutorial: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/data-center/how-to-share-a-folder-in-windows-server-2012/)

I'm not very familiar with Windows, specially with Windows Server, hopefully someone can  point me in the right direction, I've already wasted more time on this then I care to admit.

#### EDIT 1:

This is the shared folder setup on the INSTANCE 1:
[image]

And this is the error I get on the INSTANCE 2 when I try to access the folder:
[image]

Comment: Security group only required if EC2 instance reside in different subnet. For your case, check your Windows OS firewall setting first.

Comment: @mootmoot that's not correct. Subnet membership is not relevant here at all. EC2 instances cannot access each other unless a security group of which the instance is a member allows the traffic.  EC2 instances that are members of the same security group cannot even access each other unless the group allows access from itself to itself.

Comment: @Dan -- The security group settings look good. What problem are you experiencing? Can you see the Shared Volume from the other machine? Please provide more details about where things are going wrong.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot : thanks for the correction

Comment: Windows share folder use this port to take the connection, add this to your security group  :  `TCP` : 139, 445 .  `UDP` : 137, 138.